# I get a Dead code warning when trying to write an if condition

Tags: java

I got a Dead code warning for this code:

```
Topic topic = findTopicByID(point.getIDTopic());

if (topic != null)
{
   ...
}
else if (topic == null)
{
    // I get Dead code warning for every thing I write here!
}
```

Sometimes when I get a warning but everything look OK, I restart IDE and I don't get that warning anymore! but this time...

**EDIT:**

```
public Topic findTopicByID(int IDTopic) {
    for (Topic topic : topics)
        if (topic.getID() == IDTopic)
            return topic;
    return null;
}
```

Edit:
Full code here:

```
Topic topic = Res.getSchedule().getTopicBox().findTopicByID(point.getIDTopic());
            Section section =     topic.findSectionByID(point.getIDSection());

            if (topic != null)
            {
                View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.daily_day_day_row, lLDoneWorks, false);

                TextView tVLabel = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.daily_day_day_row_label);
                TextView tVNum = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.daily_day_day_row_num);
                TextView tVTopic = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.daily_day_day_row_topic);
                TextView tVSection = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.daily_day_day_row_section);

                int color = topic.getColor();
                tVLabel.setBackgroundColor(color);
                tVNum.setTextColor(color);
                tVTopic.setTextColor(color);
                tVSection.setTextColor(color);

                tVLabel.setText(topic.getName().substring(0,1).toUpperCase(Locale.US));
                tVNum.setText(Integer.toString(point.getCount()));
                tVTopic.setText(topic.getName());
                if (point.getIDSection() != Point.DEFAULT_SECTION)
                    tVSection.setText(section.getName());

                lLDoneWorks.addView(rowView);
            }
            else if (topic == null)
            {
                TopicArchived archivedTopic = Res.getSchedule().getTopicBox()
                            .findArchivedTopicByID(point.getIDTopic());
                    if (archivedTopic == null)
                        removedTopicsPoint += point.getCount();
                    else
                        archivedTopicsPoint += point.getCount();
            }
```

Comment: Can `findTopicByID` return null? Or does it thrown an exception if the topic isn't found? If it doesn't return null, maybe the IDE is smart enough to realise that `topic` can never be null, and therefore that code can't be reached.

Comment: I do not get this warning for second if condition, I get it for EVERYTHING I write in the second statement block.

Comment: The dead code warning should be on the `else if (topic == null)` line instead of everything below it. It is a wrong indication of the IDE.

Comment: Even if I delete `if (topic == null)` I still get this warning

Comment: You know the `if (topic == null)` is redundant.

Comment: Most likely the code isn't exactly as you presented it.  There is some detail you are missing, do you call `topic.method()` before the `if` statement?

Comment: Peter is right, I used `topic.method()` before if condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of this line:

```
Section section =     topic.findSectionByID(point.getIDSection());
```

if `topic` is null, you have a NullPointerException there, and the rest of the code is not reached. Therefore every check on the nullness of `topic` that would come afterwards is irrelevant: the compiler knows that `topic` is not null after that line.

You should put that line inside the first branch of your `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

You could code

```
if (topic != null)
{
   ...
}
else
{
   ...
}
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely the compiler misinterpreting the goal of the condition. Rewrite it as:

```
if (topic != null) {
   ...
}
else {
    // Code
}
```

In the else condition `topic` is logically *guaranteed* to be null. If it wasn't null the `if` block was taken and the `else` would not be.

Comment: Why should it complain about the code _in_ the the then-branch, then?

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm guessing it's likely OP's misunderstanding/misinterpretation from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on your code.

```
if(topic != null) {
} else { // here topic definitely not null, so the your if is redundant.
}
```

Comment: It definitely *is* null if it gets to the `else`.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is overkill, I think.  Why not just:

```
if (topic != null)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    // It must be null if it gets here
}
```